# Ajax after ajax request, submit form normal way

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have ajax request:

```
<script>
        $("#abc_form_submit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //........
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               dataType: 'json',
               data: $("#abc_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(data)
               {
                    if(data.success == 'false') {
// show errors
                    } else {
                        // SUBMIT NORMAL WAY. $("#abc_from").submit() doesnt work.
                    }
               }
             });

        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
    </script>
```

And php

```
.....
return $this->paypalController(params, etc...) // which should redirect to other page
.....
```

How should i make that ajax request if success, submit form normal way, because now if I redirect (at PHP) its only return response, but i need that this ajax request would handle php code as normal form submit (if success)

Dont suggest "window.location" please.

Comment: Why do you want to submit the form twice?  If you're going to submit the form "the normal way" then don't bother with AJAX in the first place.

Comment: When you say the `$("#abc_from").submit()` doesn't work, what doesn't work about it because that's the way to do it?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: @David because its in modal and i need show errors without reloading, but if its passes, then i need normal way

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius: If it "passes" then the form has *already been submitted*, so why submit it again?  That design makes no sense.  Generally when submitting a form via AJAX there's some meaningful response for success or failure.  In the case of failure, show the errors.  (Which you're doing.)  In the case of success, respond to that success.  Maybe make changes to the UI, maybe send the user to another page, etc.  It sounds like you want to send the user to another page.  So do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a result variable that you update after a succesful AJAX request?

```
<script>
    $("#abc_form_submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form if not succeded
    var result = false;
    //........
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           dataType: 'json',
           async: false,
           data: $("#abc_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
                if(data.success == 'false') {
                    // show errors
                } else {
                    // SUBMIT NORMAL WAY. $("#abc_from").submit() doesnt work.
                    result = true;
                }
           }
         });

    return result; 
});
</script>
```

Comment: I dont know why, result variable isn't getting TRUE. if I put console.log("debug") to else{ ... } statement it prints out, but "result" isnt changing to true...

Comment: My mistake. result doesn't change because you're doing an asynchronous AJAX call, so the *click* function is returning before the AJAX call finished...

Comment: What can i do/change ?

Comment: You're trying to validate the form asynchronously... Just changed the code to do it synchronously.

Comment: It says to me "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/" and doesn't work. Though, I added this to the $("#abc_form").submit() event. does click matter?

Answer (score 2):

I would add a class to the form to test if your ajax has already occured. if it has just use the normal click funciton.

Something like:

```
$('form .submit').click(function(e) {
  if (!$('form').hasClass('validated'))
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Your code here
    $.post(url, values, function(data) {
        if (success)
        {
          $('form').addClass('validated');
          $('form .submit').click();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice one, but if i change (for example with firebug) class=validated, then i could "hack" this. It means i need to validate form 2 times in php. No other way ?

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius That is very true but that is possible with any javascript implementation. No matter what your javascript does it will be possible for the user to hack it. The user has access to all js, css, and html on the page. Most validation and submit take place on the same call to prevent such things. If validation failed reload the page with form values. If succeed then submit. If you want to validate without a page load you will still have to validate again when you submit the data no matter which solution you choose. The user can just edit your js to skip validation either way.

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius If this really is for validation most implementations do a javascript only validation for UX and then a proper php validation on submit for security.

Comment: I have made validation server-side, i just need to submit the same form but not ajax way.

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius If you return to the page between validation and submit you must validate a second time or you will have a massive security hole. Not much more to say on that topic. Perhaps a better explanation on why you want to validate and submit in 2 different calls instead of one would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before where I needed the form to submit to two places, one for tracking and another to the actual form action.

It only worked by submitting it programatically when you put the form.submit() behind a setTimeout.  500ms seems to have done the trick for me.  I'm not sure why browsers have trouble submitting the form programatically when they are attempting to submit them traditionally, but this seems to sort it out.

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("#abc_from").submit(); }, 500);
```

One thing to keep in mind though once it submits, that's it for the page, it's gone.  If you still want whatever processes are running on the page to run, you will need to set the target of the form to _blank so that it will submit in a new tab.